# SQL Server 2012 - facing installation error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I was trying to install SQL Server 2012 but I get an error

> Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.VisualC, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Error code 0x84B10001.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried the same installation file in another machine? Have you tried re-downloading installation file?

Comment: I tried re downloading but same error and i tried on different machine and it installs as on that machine coz "Microsoft.VisualC" assembly is there in GAC in other machine but it is not there in GAC in my system

Comment: Could you identify which component caused failure by reading log?

Comment: Here is log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftnt3qmy5url9ym/Detail_LandingPage.txt?dl=0